# sinon stub a method that was executed in then call of promise

Tags: unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon, chai

```
describe("/test" , ()=> {

    // separate class 2
    class2 = {

        // function that i wanna stub
    hi: function () {
        return "hi";
    }
    }

// separate class 1
    class1 = {

        // function that i have stubbed and tested
         method1: function() {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               resolve(num);

            })
        }

    }

    // method that i will execute
    var parent= function (){

        class1.method1().then(()=>{

            class2.hi();

        })

    }

    // the test
    it("should stub hi method",()=>{


        var hiTest = sinon.stub(class2, 'hi').resolves(5);
        var method1Test = sinon.stub(class1 , 'method1').resolves(5);

     // this start the execution of the promise with then call
        parent();

        // this works fine and test pass
        expect(method1Test.calledOnce.should.be.true);

        // this doesn't work although i executed the function
        expect(hiTest.calledOnce.should.be.true);

    })

})
```

**what i wanna do is test the hi method correctly** .. because when i test if the method is executed once or not

although i executed it in the then call of the promise it doesn't show that and it make the calledOnce test fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are testing the code as if it is synchronous, when it is not (as you are using `Promise`).

---

To be able to test this properly we need to be able to hook onto the promise chain that is started with `parent`calling `class1.method1`.

We can do this by returning the promise that calling `class1.method1` returns.

In terms of the test itself, we need to make sure `Mocha` doesnt end the test while we are waiting for the promises, so we use the `done` callback parameter to tell `Mocha` when we think the test is finished.

---

```
describe("/test", ()=> {
  class2 = {
    hi: function () {
      return "hi";
    }
  }

  class1 = {
    method1: function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(num);
      })
    }
  }

  var parent = function (){
    return class1.method1().then(()=>{
      class2.hi();
    })
  }

  it("should stub hi method", (done)=> {
    var hiTest = sinon.stub(class2, 'hi').returns(5);
    var method1Test = sinon.stub(class1 , 'method1').resolves(5);

    parent().then(() => {
      expect(method1Test.calledOnce.should.be.true);
      expect(hiTest.calledOnce.should.be.true);
      done();
    });
  })
})
```